# React state is not changing after the props change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm using redux with react, In my react state I'm assigning some state properties to the props but in my state the accounts are changing but the loading property doesn't change, I also tried to update the state in componentdidupdate but when I try to do that I get maximum update depth exceeded

In AllAccounts the accounts property is updating when the accounts are done fetching and the props change but the same doesn't happen for the loading property, It is set to the first value when it changes when it is set to true, The prop value is changing for loading but it is not changing in the state

This is my component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getAccounts,
  deleteAccounts,
  addAccount,
} from "../../../actions/accountActions";
import { getUsersForTenant } from "../../../actions/userActions";

import { Drawer } from "antd";
import getSortUrl from "../../../utils/getSortUrl";
import "../tablepage.css";
import Table from "../../../components/Table/Table";
import SearchHeader from "../../../components/SearchHeader/SearchHeader";
import Loading from "../../../components/Loading/Loading";
import AddAccount from "../../../components/AddEntities/AddAccount/AddAccount";
class AllAccounts extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    this.setSort = this.setSort.bind(this);
    this.deleteRows = this.deleteRows.bind(this);
    this.toggleDrawer = this.toggleDrawer.bind(this);
    this.addAccount = this.addAccount.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    page: 0,
    size: 50,
    loading: this.props.loading,
    accounts: this.props.accounts,
    sort: undefined,
    selectedItems: [],
    checkboxActive: false,
    drawerVisible: false,
    columns: [
      {
        key: "name",
        title: "Name",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: true,
        type: "string",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: true,
      },
      {
        key: "companyDomain",
        title: "Company Domain",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: true,
        type: "string",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "industrySector.name",
        title: "Industry Sector",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: true,
        type: "string",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "picture",
        title: "Picture",
        enabled: false,
        searchable: false,
        type: "picture",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "nbrEmployees",
        title: "No. Employees",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: true,
        type: "number",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "fixedPhone",
        title: "Phone",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: true,
        type: "string",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "source.name",
        title: "Source",
        enabled: false,
        searchable: true,
        type: "string",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "linkedIn",
        title: "LinkedIn",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: false,
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "social",
        title: "Social Networks",
        title: "Social Networks",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: false,
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "twitterPage",
        title: "Twitter",
        title: "twitter",
        enabled: false,
        bindCol: "social",
        bindColTitle: "Social",
        searchable: false,
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "instagramPage",
        title: "Instagram",
        enabled: false,
        searchable: false,
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },

      {
        key: "googlePlus",
        title: "Google Plus",
        enabled: false,
        searchable: false,
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "user",
        title: "User",
        enabled: false,
        searchable: false,
        type: "string",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "isCustomer",
        title: "Is Customer",
        enabled: false,
        searchable: false,
        type: "boolean",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
      {
        key: "Tags",
        title: "Tags",
        enabled: true,
        searchable: false,
        type: "string",
        selected: false,
        sortActive: false,
        sortOrder: "ASC",
        showCheckbox: false,
      },
    ],
  };

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({
      drawerVisible: !this.state.drawerVisible,
    });
  };

  deleteRows = (rows) => {
    if (rows) {
      this.props.deleteAccounts(rows, 1);

      this.setState({
        loading: true,
      });
    } else {
      const { selectedItems } = this.state;

      this.props.deleteAccounts(selectedItems, 1);

      this.setState({
        selectedItems: [],
        loading: true,
      });
    }
  };

  addAccount = (accountData) => {
    this.props.addAccount(accountData, 1);
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps, snap) {
    // if (prevProps.accounts != this.props.accounts) {
    //   this.setState({
    //     accounts: this.props.accounts,
    //     loading: false,
    //   });
    // }
    // if (prevProps.users != this.props.users) {
    //   this.setState({
    //     assignableUsers: this.props.users,
    //   });
    // }
  }

  setSort = (column) => {
    this.setState({
      sort: column,
    });
  };

  selectRow = (select, row) => {
    if (select) {
      this.setState({
        selectedItems: [...this.state.selectedItems, row],
        checkboxActive: true,
      });
    } else {
      var { selectedItems } = this.state;
      var index = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        if (selectedItems[i].id == row.id) {
          console.log(i);
          index = i;
        }
      }
      selectedItems.splice(index, 1);

      if (selectedItems.length == 0) {
        this.setState({
          selectedItems: selectedItems,
          checkboxActive: false,
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          selectedItems: selectedItems,
        });
      }
    }
  };

  fetchData = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        loading: true,
      },
      () => {
        const { page, size, sort } = this.state;
        var sortUrl = "";
        if (sort) {
          const sortKey = sort.key;
          const sortOrder = sort.sortOrder;

          sortUrl = getSortUrl(sortKey, sortOrder);
        }

        this.props.getAccounts(page, size, sortUrl);
      }
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(0, 50, undefined);
    this.props.getUsersForTenant();
  }

  toggleEnableColumn = (index) => {
    const { columns } = this.state;
    var enableOccured = false;

    columns[index].enabled = !columns[index].enabled;
    columns.forEach((col) => {
      if (!enableOccured && col.enabled) {
        col.showCheckbox = true;
        enableOccured = true;
      } else {
        col.showCheckbox = false;
      }
    });

    this.setState({
      columns: columns,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const {
      size,
      page,
      accounts,
      columns,
      loading,
      checkboxActive,
      drawerVisible,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="table-page-container">
        <Loading loading={loading} />
        <Drawer
          title="Add New Account"
          placement="right"
          closable={true}
          visible={drawerVisible}
          onClose={this.toggleDrawer}
        >
          <AddAccount
            toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer}
            assignableUsers={this.props.users}
            addAccount={this.addAccount}
          />
        </Drawer>
        <div className="breadcrumb-container"></div>
        <div className="searchbar-container">
          <SearchHeader
            columns={columns}
            checkboxActive={checkboxActive}
            fetchData={this.fetchData}
            deleteData={this.deleteRows}
            toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer}
          />
        </div>
        <Table
          size={size}
          page={page}
          data={accounts}
          checkboxActive={checkboxActive}
          module={"accounts"}
          columns={columns}
          toggleEnableColumn={this.toggleEnableColumn}
          className="table-container"
          selectRow={this.selectRow}
          fetchData={this.fetchData}
          setSort={this.setSort}
          deleteData={this.deleteRows}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    accounts: state.account.accounts,
    users: state.user.users,
    loading: state.account.loading,
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getAccounts: (page, size, sort) => dispatch(getAccounts(page, size, sort)),
    addAccount: (accountData, accountType) =>
      dispatch(addAccount(accountData, accountType)),

    deleteAccounts: (rows, accountType) =>
      dispatch(deleteAccounts(rows, accountType)),
    getUsersForTenant: () => dispatch(getUsersForTenant()),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AllAccounts);
```

This is the reducer

```
import {
  GET_ACCOUNT,
  GET_ACCOUNTS,
  GET_CUSTOMERS,
  GET_PROSPECTS,
  DELETE_ACCOUNT,
  SET_ACCOUNTS_LOADING,
  SET_ACCOUNTS_ERROR,
  CLEAR_ERRORS,
} from "../actions/types";

const defaultState = {
  accounts: [],
  customers: [],
  prospects: [],
  loading: false,
  errors: {},
};

const accountReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ACCOUNTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        accounts: action.payload,
        errors: {},
      };
    case GET_CUSTOMERS:
      return {
        ...state,
        customers: action.payload,
        errors: {},
      };
    case GET_PROSPECTS:
      return {
        ...state,
        prospects: action.payload,
        errors: {},
      };
    case CLEAR_ERRORS:
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: {},
      };
    case SET_ACCOUNTS_LOADING:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: action.payload,
      };
    case SET_ACCOUNTS_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        errors: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default accountReducer;
```

Comment: please don't ever setState in componentDidUpdate, it's like eternal loop. when a component is updating, you are saying it to update again.

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat Yes I have commented it out

Comment: i'm still not clear of what you want , but based on what you have described , seems like you want the data from the props to be updated in your local state, is it? correct me if i'm wrong yeah...if like this, then you will have to use `static getDerivedStateFromProps()` basically it will derive your updated props to flow through your local state.

Comment: @KevinMoeMyintMyat You are correct can you please give me an example on how can I use that to update the state of my component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might need is the `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)`

> This method exists for rare use cases where the state depends on changes in props over time.

In order for your props to flow through your local state, you can write a logic inside that life-cycle method.

```
 static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if (!isEqual(props.accounts,state.accounts)) {
      return {
        accounts: props.accounts
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Please take note that I am using `isEqual` from `lodash/isEqual` to deep check equality between state and props otherwise it will update everytime props flow in.

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops